# Magento: Custom module works in localhost but not in server

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Using magento 1.9 I have a custom module that should appear in the product view, it works fine on the xampp server in my localhost, but when i upload the module files to the server it doesnt work, despite it appear as enable in the System>Confinguration on Disable Modules Output. 
Is it something on my code or is the server?

This is the in the **csharls_productmeasure.xml** inside **app\etc\modules**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <csharls_productmeasure>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </csharls_productmeasure>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

This is the **config.xml** inside of **app\code\local\csharls\productmeasure\etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <config>
    <modules>
        <csharls_productmeasure>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        </csharls_productmeasure>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <productmeasure>
                <class>csharls_productmeasure_Model</class>
            </productmeasure>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <productmeasure>
                <class>csharls_productmeasure_Block</class>
            </productmeasure>
        </blocks>   
        <events>            
          <sales_quote_add_item>
           <observers>
             <productmeasure>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>csharls_productmeasure_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>updatePrice</method>
                  </productmeasure>
              </observers>
           </sales_quote_add_item>
       </events>
    </global>
    <frontend>
      <routers>
          <productmeasure>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>csharls_productmeasure</module>
                    <frontName>productmeasure</frontName>
                </args>
            </productmeasure>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <csharls_productmeasure>
                    <file>csharls_productmeasure.xml</file>
                </csharls_productmeasure>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the cache?

Comment: @Karl Yes I did without sucess.

Comment: @Csharls what changes you did in the layout ?, I have a similar issue,  my block doesn't appear in live server.,

Comment: @jacr1614 my problem was the name of the modules and the namespace were in lowercase this is fine in windows but in server as is based on unix or linux it has a problem with the paths. so doble check the names of your modules folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appeared int the Server because it runs on linux while my XAMPP localhost is on Windows. Windows is not case sensitive while linux is case sensitive. So when i was creating the folders and files, i wrote the names in lowercase to avoid this but ironically that was the problem, in Magento the inital leter have to be Capital leter,

so my module folders were wrote in lowercase like this:

**csharls/productmeasure/...** it works in windows but not in linux.

I changed it to inital capital letter like this:

**Csharls/Productmeasure/...** this works in windows and linux.

Also changed the namespace of Blocks, controllers, Model files and the name of the files all of them has to be intial capitalLetter, all the references in the .xml files aswell.

The template **csharls_prodcutmeasure.xml** file and layout **csharls_productmeasure.phtml** file where the only ones that i didnt rename.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Please permission your file 755 in server

Step 2 : Check your php version local & live are same or not

Step 3 : Refresh the cache

Comment: I Check and it have 755 on folders and 644 on files.  and PHP is the same version in both local and live. I refresh the cache too. still not working.

Comment: Can you send me your code in email then i will check it local & live.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  i finnally found that the file names cant be in lowercase because it gives a wrong path in the live server that runs unix/linux.